# Enhanced session with Lubuntu guest in Hyper-V

Tags: lubuntu, virtualization, windows-10, lxde, hyper-v

Did anybody find a way to make Enhanced session work in Hyper-V (Windows 10) with an Lubuntu 18.04 LTS guest?

After creating a new VM with a fresh Lubuntu 'minimal' installation, the Basic session works fine. To get support for resizing, and shared folders and clipboard I tried enabling Enhanced session by running the `install.sh` from [linux-vm-tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/linux-vm-tools/wiki/Onboarding:-Ubuntu#manual-config---ubuntu-1804).

However, this doesn't work as the script assumes a GNOME desktop. Has anybody been able to modify this to work with Lubuntu and LXDE? It would be very useful for single-purpose VMs, where a GNOME desktop and applications are overkill.

(edit)

I've naively tried patching the [`install.sh`](https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools/blob/master/ubuntu/18.04/install.sh) as follows, based on the environment of a running Lubuntu. But as it doesn't work, there must be some other Ubuntu-specific detail in the script that doesn't apply to Lubuntu. Anybody made it work?

```
61,62c61,64
< export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
< export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
---
> export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=LXDE
> export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=Lubuntu
> export DESKTOP_SESSION=Lubuntu
> export GDMSESSION=Lubuntu
```

Comment: The `install.sh` is ASCII; can't you just adjust it, particularly the XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP bit?   I've no experience of using it as you want (on w10) but I've seen many blogs about adjusting that for other virtual environments (both XFCE and LXDE).

Comment: Thanks @guiverc. I also suspect that some simple patch to the `install.sh` could make it work. 
It's the Enhanced session I'm after, and I guess it would apply to all Hyper-V hosts (not just W10). Any links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I get it to work. To what it seems, there is a lot that can be "removed" from the `install.sh` script in order to make this work on **Lubuntu** 18.04 on the latest Windows 10 build. So my changes were:

- Remove everything from the `/etc/xrdp/startubuntu.sh` script less the line that calls the `startwm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

- Add `lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE` to the end of the `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` file.
- I'm not sure if this is needed, but add a file to your home dir called `.xsession` with the content `lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE`.
- I also changed toggled the comments on the first lines related to the HWE kernel packages:

```
#HWE=""
HWE="-hwe-18.04"
```

I hope this fixes your problem. Some parts of this solutions were based on [this blogpost](https://www.fancyaddress.com/blog/linux/xrdp-with-lxde-on-ubuntu-server-18-04/).